# How to read thumbprints of signing certificates from Federation Metadata XML?

Tags: c#, adfs, federation

I want to be able to monitor the signing certificates of trusted parties ADFS. One approach is to read the Federation Metadata XML manually and parse the KeyInfo - elements and create the `X509Certificate` from the base64-encoded data: [see this good article](https://www.msxfaq.de/cloud/authentifizierung/adfs_monitoring.htm)

After some reading i found that `MetadataSerializer` I can easily create `EntityDescriptor` for further investigations from the XML. As an example, one can get the Metadata for Windows Live login:

```
string uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/38cda3b4-71fa-4748-a48e-e50ef1ebfe00/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml";
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(uri))
{
    var serializer = new MetadataSerializer();
    serializer.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
    EntityDescriptor metadata = (EntityDescriptor)serializer.ReadMetadata(reader);
}
```

The descriptor exposes a property `RoleDescriptors` which simply wraps up all the descriptors inside the metadata, including the security keys for encrypting or signing. But I am not able to access the certificate data in order to read out the thumbprints. See the simplified code below:

```
// metadata from above
SecurityKeyIdentifierClause keyIdentifier = metadata.RoleDescriptors.First().Keys.First().KeyInfo[0];
// keyIdentifier.certificate ... => private, exposes XCertificate2
```

Any ideas to get the thumbprint with that approach rather than the manual XML parsing?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all comes down to using the `X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause` rather than the abstract base of it:

```
 X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause keyIdentifier = metadata.RoleDescriptors.First().Keys.First().KeyInfo[0] as X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause;

 if ( keyIdentifier != null )
 {
      X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(keyIdentifier.GetX509RawData());
      string thumbprint     = cert.Thumbprint;
 }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: This worked for ADFS 3
https://-your-ADFS-url-/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml